# Encoding necessary for numerical data that can be summarised into a few groups

Tags: preprocessing

I have an input parameter that have 200 values.  However, among the 200 values, there are only 3 distinct values. For example, like this:

## X1

10
14
14
10
22
22
10
10
14
.
.
.

Should I treat this parameter as a categorical input and encode it before feeding to a neural network model?

However, if the parameter is treated as a categorical input, then it cannot accept any new values? So do we still consider it as numerical input?

Comment: Give us some context about this variable, what it represents, and why you only have 3 distinct values.

Comment: The parameter from a manufacturing process.  Each value is the average value of that parameter X1 during the processing of a batch.   If there are 10 values for X1, then there are 10 batches.

Hope this clarifies the context

Comment: If this is a parameter which can take on different values in the future then it might be better to code is as numerical... although if the new value will be quite different from the ones that the model has seen the results might be less than ideal.